# Why am I getting this RunTime Error: "RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin" after converting my .py to .exe? (Python 3.7 and Windows 11)

Tags: python, runtime-error, windows-11

I'm very new to Python and I'm using this program to make math worksheets for my kids.  It works fine in Python, but when I try to convert it to .exe using PyInstaller AND auto-py-to-exe I get this error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MathPractice.py", line 9, in <module>
RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin"
```

[Windows Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMTwz.jpg)

Here is where my code asks for input.  Any suggestions for other improvements are welcome, but mostly I'd just like to have an executable that my wife can use.  Thank you!

```
low_number = int(input("What would you like the low end of the number range to be?\n"))
high_number = int(input("What would you like the high end of the number range to be?\n"))
mathtype = "NOT"
mathlist = ["+", "-", "/", "*"]
print_key = input("Would you like an answer key also? (y/n)\n")
```

Comment: `pyinstaller --console --onefile MathPractice.py` will probably solve your problem i would suspect that it by default does not export a console enabled executable, since *most* executables use a GUI ... (but console is plenty acceptable to do :) ) ie (`pyinstaller --onefile MathPractice.py` is the same as `pyinstaller --no-console --onefile MathPractice.py`

Comment: Joran, YOU ARE A GENIUS!  It worked perfectly!   Thank you for your quick response!